# Qt C++. Предупреждение при запуске проекта

Tags: c++, qt, warning

У меня при запуске проекта появляется такое предупреждение
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить и на сколько это важно?

Comment: установите эту переменную и посмотрите, что изменится, возможно ничего. Это в qtcreator `Project/Run/Environment/Add`

Answer (score 1):

Ваш гном трудится на базе X11, а прога по умолчанию пытается работать через wayland.

два варианта чтобы избавиться от предупреждения:
запускать так

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland
./your_app
```

или так

```
./your_app -platform=wayland
```

Это естественно если доступен wayland. В противном случае можно форсить работу через x11 указав `-platform=xcb`

Comment: Спасибо большое